# Trying to group different values that have some similarities in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm parsing a JSON that kinda looks like this:

```
[{"acc":P1,"Lenght":855,..."MBDB-1":{"source_id":"2btp_A","regions":[[70,73],[231,234]],"content_fraction":0.033,"content_count":8},"MBDB-2":{...},"MDB-2":{...}},\
{"acc":P2,"Lenght":145,...,"MBDB-14":{...},...}]
```

And I'm trying to generate a dictionary with only the information that I want (ie, `"acc", "Lenght"`) and all the information INSIDE the keys that starts with "MBDB", no matter what comes after that (the actual file is huge, with a lot of information that I don't really need).

For the first two items, it's fairly easy. This is what I got:

```
import json 

my_dict= dict.fromkeys(['ID', 'MISSING','LENGHT'])
with open("...\mypath\Json1.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    for i in data:
        if "acc" in i:
            my_dict["ID"]=i["acc"]
```

But I'm really lost on how to append each of the values of "MBDB-something" to the `MISSING` key. As far as I understand, I can't use `startswith()`, because I'm working with a dict (generated by `json.loads()`).

This is what the result should look like:

```
  ID LENGHT source_id             regions content_count

0 P1    855    2btp_A [[70,73],[231,234]]             8
1 P1    855       ...               [...]             #   
2 P2    145       ...               [...]             #
```

So I can later use `.explode` and perform different operations on some of the information that these keys hold.
I feel that I'm out of my league to solve this issue, so any advice is welcome!
EDIT: I've edited the desired output to be the content of the different keys INSIDE all the "MBDB" keys.

Comment: is "MISSING" values list or dictionary? and why can't you use `startswith()`?

Comment: A list, so I don't have dicts inside my dict. The best option would be to have all the individual values of "MBDB-#" under their own key, but I can do that afterwards.

Comment: you can't store key value pairs inside a list

Comment: Good to know. I edited the desired output, where now it only holds the values. They are still pairs, so I don't know if it's going to have the same issue.

Comment: no it doesn't work try using list of dicts or dictionary

Comment: Your output for MISSING still doesn't make sense. What's wrong with having a list of dict? Also, is the dictionary structure consistent or does it vary?

Comment: Ok, now I've got rid of MISSING, and maybe it's easier to get only the content inside the different "MBDB" keys, that have consistent names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the key are consistent in the json object, you can insert one item in a list based on every "MBDB" key that you find.

```
# load data
with open("...\mypath\Json1.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

out = [] # final output
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if "MBDB" in k: 
            out.append({
                "ID": d["acc"],
                "LENGTH": d["Lenght"],
                "source_id": v["source_id"],
                "regions": v["regions"],
                "content_count": v["content_count"]
            })
```

Final output here will be a list of dict. you can use pandas to convert it into a dataframe.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(out)

# output
 ID  LENGTH source_id                 regions  content_count
0  P1     855    2btp_A  [[70, 73], [231, 234]]              8
1  P1     855    2btp_B  [[70, 73], [231, 234]]              8
2  P2     855    2btp_A  [[70, 73], [231, 234]]              8
3  P2     855    2btp_B  [[70, 73], [231, 234]]              8
```

Comment: Great answer! It totally worked. As you said, now I can convert it to a df and work with pandas, I'm more familiar with this type of structure. Thanks!